# Divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I have to use the divergence theorem to solve

$\iint F \cdot ds$ where $F(x,y,z)=x^3 \hat{\imath}+y^3\hat{\jmath}+z^3\hat{k}$ and $S$ is the surface of the solid rounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the planes $z=0$ and $z=2$

any help ? Thanks

Comment: The divergence theorem lets you write $\iint F \cdot ds = \iiint \nabla F \,dV$. So, now you just need to compute the divergence of $F$, set up a volume integral over the solid, and then compute this integral. Which part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to start , can you help me

Comment: The div F I got 3x^2+3y^2+ 3z^2

Comment: Are you having trouble setting up the integral, then?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've computed the divergence, the next step is to take the integral of the divergence over the region.  In this case, that is
$$
\iiint_R \nabla \cdot F(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx = 
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_0^2 \nabla \cdot F(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx 
$$
But perhaps you'll find it easier to change this integral over to cylindrical coordinates instead.

Comment: Hello. I have trouble with your answer - can I change the $dxdydz$ to another coordinates? What would be the cylindrical coordinates and their range in this case?

Comment: @PeterKowalski I don't know what you mean when you say *"what would be the cylindrical coordinates and their range in this case?"*. If you have further questions, perhaps you should make a post of your own referring to this question.

Comment: As advised, I created a post with my question here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418983/divergence-theorem-and-applying-cylindrical-coordinates