# Divergence theorem and applying cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

This time my question is based on this example [Divergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848962/divergence-theorem)

I wanted to change the solution proposed by Omnomnomnom to cylindrical coordinates.
$$
\iiint_R \nabla \cdot F(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx = 
\iiint_R 3x^2+3y^2+3z^2\,dz\,dy\,dx =
$$
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^2 3r+3z^2r\,dz\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 6r+8r\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} 28 \pi r \,dr = 14 \pi$$
Which is a different result than the one obtained from calculating the triple integral proposed by Omnomnomnom (with the help of wolframalpha Triple Integral Calculator) - it gives $34.5575$

What have I done wrong?

EDIT:
As suggested by DeltaG:
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^2 3r^2+3z^2r\,dz\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 6r^2+8r\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} 12 \pi r^2+16 \pi r \,dr = 12 \pi$$

Which unfortunately still is not equal to $34.5575$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost an $r$: $3x^2+3y^2 = 3r^2$, rather than $3r$. The $r$ just before the differentials should be distributed to both term in the integrand as well.

Response to edit: the $z$ is fine now, but that $r$ at the end isn't making it into the first term, I think.
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (3r^2+3z^2)r\,dz\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (6r^2+8)r\,d \varphi \,dr =\int_{0}^{1} (12 \pi r^3+16 \pi r) \,dr = 3\pi+8\pi=11 \pi$$

Comment: At first I substituted $x^2+y^2=1$. Thank you for your suggestion,  but still the obtained answer is presumably incorrect. Please check my Edit.

Comment: It's that r at the end. Check edited comment.